# Link/Reference DLL - reference succeeded, build failed --> C#/.NET

Tags: c#, dll, reference, linker

I have 2 .NET compiled DLL which i want to link in another project. So i reference this 2 DLLs in my new Project(Add Reference-Browse - pick dll).
 Everything seems to work fine, i can access the classes and methods in referenced DLLs, but when i try to buid the new project, the compiler tells me:

```
    Error   14  The type or namespace name 'Business'
 could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Do i have to link them somewhere else ?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you fully qualified the correct namespace with a 'using' directive at the top of the new project?

Comment: Off topic, but in case you aren't you should copy the dll's you are referencing into your project structure (perhaps under an "Includes" folder). If you add a reference like you said and the dll's are not in your project folder, then when you move the project to another computer the dll's will not move with it, breaking your code. (And NEVER directly reference a dll in a bin folder... it'll only cause you trouble, pain and sorrow.)

Comment: Thanq you @Cyborgx37. Unfortunately, that is exactly what i was intending, to refference the DLLs manually by copying them in my bin folder, in the new project. What are my options ? :( I mean, which folder i should choose?   Later Edit : I tried to copy them in my project -- Still the same error :(

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen when the DDL has a different .NET Framework version than the project that reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the CopyLocal to 'true' for each reference. 
If CopyLocal is set to false, the referenced DLL must be within the scope of your project (think, bin and obj folders)